# How do you work out the average of a sum function within a temp table?

Tags: sql

I have created a temp table that lists each client's invoice(s), plus the number of days it took to pay the invoice. A client can have more than one invoice.

Instead of this, I would just like the temp table to list each client once, along with the AVERAGE number of days it took to pay all of their invoices.

Any tips on how to do this would be much appreciated.

Thanks

```
select 
c.client_code,  
b.bill_num,
b.bill_date, 
ba.TRAN_DATE,
sum(datediff(Day,b.BILL_DATE, ba.TRAN_DATE)) as Days_To_Pay

into #tempG1

from blt_bill b
left outer join blt_billm bm on b.tran_uno = bm.bill_tran_uno
left outer join BLT_BILL_AMT ba on bm.BILLM_UNO = ba.BILLM_UNO
left outer join hbm_matter m on bm.matter_uno = m.matter_uno
left outer join hbm_client c on m.client_uno = c.client_uno

where b.total_bill_amt > 0.0
and bm.ar_status NOT IN ('P','X')
and ba.TRAN_TYPE in ('CR','crx')

group by c.client_code,b.bill_num,b.bill_date,ba.TRAN_DATE

select * from #tempG1

Drop Table #tempG1
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with temp tables, but this should work (tested on a simliar scenario on MySQL8 and assuming that #tempG1 return results):

```
select 
c.client_code,  
b.bill_num,
b.bill_date, 
ba.TRAN_DATE,
sum(datediff(Day,b.BILL_DATE, ba.TRAN_DATE)) as Days_To_Pay


from blt_bill b
left outer join blt_billm bm on b.tran_uno = bm.bill_tran_uno
left outer join BLT_BILL_AMT ba on bm.BILLM_UNO = ba.BILLM_UNO
left outer join hbm_matter m on bm.matter_uno = m.matter_uno
left outer join hbm_client c on m.client_uno = c.client_uno

where b.total_bill_amt > 0.0
and bm.ar_status NOT IN ('P','X')
and ba.TRAN_TYPE in ('CR','crx')

group by c.client_code,b.bill_num,b.bill_date,ba.TRAN_DATE

into #tempG1
############################
SELECT temp.client_code, AVG(temp.Days_To_Pay) 
FROM (select * from #tempG1) as temp 
GROUP BY temp.client_code
############################
#### Do you see results if drop? ####
Drop Table #tempG1
```

Note that I put #tempG1, at the bottom of your SELECT request, but might not be what want to achieve, not sure if you want to include your JOIN conditions or not.

Or you could do without temp table(including your join conditions):

```
SELECT   temp.client_code, AVG(temp.Days_To_Pay) 
(
   select 
   c.client_code,  
   b.bill_num,
   b.bill_date, 
   ba.TRAN_DATE,
   sum(datediff(Day,b.BILL_DATE, ba.TRAN_DATE)) as Days_To_Pay


   from blt_bill b
   left outer join blt_billm bm on b.tran_uno = bm.bill_tran_uno
   left outer join BLT_BILL_AMT ba on bm.BILLM_UNO = ba.BILLM_UNO
   left outer join hbm_matter m on bm.matter_uno = m.matter_uno
   left outer join hbm_client c on m.client_uno = c.client_uno

   where b.total_bill_amt > 0.0
   and bm.ar_status NOT IN ('P','X')
   and ba.TRAN_TYPE in ('CR','crx')

   group by c.client_code,b.bill_num,b.bill_date,ba.TRAN_DATE
) as temp

GROUP BY temp.client_code
```

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a simple aggregation:

```
select c.client_code, avg(datediff(Day, b.BILL_DATE, ba.TRAN_DATE)) as Days_To_Pay
from blt_bill b join
     blt_billm bm
     on b.tran_uno = bm.bill_tran_uno join
     BLT_BILL_AMT ba
     on bm.BILLM_UNO = ba.BILLM_UNO join
     hbm_matter m on bm.matter_uno = m.matter_uno join
     hbm_client c 
     on m.client_uno = c.client_uno
where b.total_bill_amt > 0.0 and
      bm.ar_status not in ('P', 'X') and
      ba.TRAN_TYPE in ('CR', 'crx')
group by c.client_code;
```

Note that you do not need outer joins.  The `where` clause is turning most of them into `inner join`s anyway.  Plus, if you are aggregating by the client code, then presumably you want a non-`NULL` value.